# 13.04 64-bit install not enough disk space

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, 64-bit, vmware

I installed 13.04 64-bit in VMWare player and during the update process the system runs out of disk. I installed from an ISO image, I did not enter any disk sizes or similar, everything was done automatically. How can I make the boot partition bigger? I am happy to reinstall if that's necessary. Current output from df is:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        4061888 3768088     84136  98% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             8204812       4   8204808   1% /dev
tmpfs            1642872     776   1642096   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             8214352     152   8214200   1% /run/shm
none              102400      24    102376   1% /run/user
```

Comment: If you could run df -h and move the output over by 4 lines it will format correctly as shown on your screen. It appears that you are 98% full in / (root) and the installer does not have enough room to write the data it is trying to write/read or process. Would recommend a reinstall with more virtual disk space.

Comment: Thanks, but virtual disk space is already 20GB, however it doesn't seem to automatically increase the size over 4GB.

Comment: What file system is the virtual disk on? Could it be FAT32? If so, 4GB is the size limit that FAT32 can handle, and you'll need to format that partition, or recreate the virtual disk on a different one.

Answer (score 0):

If you increased the size of the virtual disk after installing, then you need to enlarge the partition to use the new space.  Boot the vm from the install/live cd, and fire up `gparted`, and resize the partition to use the free space at the end.